# XGBoost Java Implementation : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when using DMatrix from XGBoost Package

Tags: java, dll, xgboost

I'm using eclipse luna with maven plugin in Windows 8.1. I've already put xgboost4j.dll (renaming libxgboost.dll which is produced from running "make" in xgboost folder) in xgboost4j/src/main/resources/lib/xgboost4j.dll by running create_Jni.bat. When I'm running BasicWalkThrough.java in example package, it output the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoostJNI.XGDMatrixCreateFromFile(Ljava/lang/String;I[J)I
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoostJNI.XGDMatrixCreateFromFile(Native Method)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.DMatrix.(DMatrix.java:83)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.example.BasicWalkThrough.main(BasicWalkThrough.java:52)
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey... I am having the same issue in windows 7. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

xgboost is not currently supported on Windows, see here:
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1051

On linux/OS X, I resolved this issue by setting JAVA_HOME to the jdk directory and installing gcc.

Comment: Minor update: the current version does support Windows. Unofficial JARs for Linux OS X and Windows are available [here](https://github.com/criteo-forks/xgboost-jars).